# Apps with no data collection

Tags: flutter

So I am totally new to Flutter and am looking into making apps. I have been thinking something and don't know if it is possible or not.
I was looking into making these expense trackers or habit tracker apps (they look like standard beginner stuff.), then I started wondering if it would be possible to allow the user to transfer data from their hive database to google sheets by logging into their google accounts or something? Basically every user can have their own database online and manage it as they want?
Is this done in practice or am I just being delusional?

Thanks in advance! :)